# Combine 2 foreach loops into one with different logic

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm looking for the way to combine 2 foraech loops into one (merge 2 functions):
The result function should return both: ($is - boolean & $d - array).
Traversable data in both functions - the same.
Is it possible? What will be a good solution for that?

```
public function func1($p, $c) {
    
    $is = 0;
    if (!empty($p)) {
        foreach($p as $k=>$v) {
                
            if ((!empty($c['prod']) && $c['prod'] == $v['ref'] && $c['status'])) {
                $is = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $is;
}

public function func2($p) {
    
    $d      = [];
    
    if (!empty($p)) {
        foreach($p as $k=>$v) {
                
            $prod = [
                'name'      => $v['name'], 
                'price'     => $v['price'],
                'reference' => $v['ref']                    
            ];
            
            $d[] = $prod;           
        }
    }
    
    return $d;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just combine what you are currently doing in both then, and remove the `break` statement (because you still want to process the rest of the records after that, for the second part of your functionality.) And since a function can only return _one_ data item, you will have to put $is and $d into an array or object then, and return that.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide some example of the code?

Comment: This is fairly trivial. Please make an attempt yourself first at least, instead of reflexively asking for an example right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take, but not tested.

```php
public function func3($p, $c) {
    $is = 0;
    $d = [];
    if (!empty($p)) {
        foreach($p as $k=>$v) {
            $d[] = [
                'name'      => $v['name'], 
                'price'     => $v['price'],
                'reference' => $v['ref']                    
            ];
         
            if ($is === 0 && (!empty($c['prod']) && $c['prod'] == $v['ref'] && $c['status'])) {
                $is = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return [$is, $d];
}
```